# filter table info by other table id

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

**funcionarios**

```
idfunc | nomefunc | rg | cpf | etc...|
 10000 | example1 | 00 | 00  | etc...|
 10001 | example2 | 00 | 00  | etc...|
```

**ferias**

```
idferias | idfunc    | ferias...........|
00001  ..| ......... | example fe...    |
00002  ..| ......... | example fe...    |
00003  ..| ......... | example fe...    |
```

i want to get a list of items from `ferias` filtered by each `idfunc` from `funcionarios`.

I've tried this code:

```
<?php
include('mysql.php');
if ($db_found) {
        $SQL = "SELECT idfunc FROM ferias AS idfunc FROM funcionarios";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);

        while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {

                echo $db_field['idfunc']."<br>";
        }
} else {

print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);

}
?>
```

without success.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You need to learn about [SQL joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29). Your sample query isn't anything close to valid sql.

Comment: Can you show actual `idfunc` values from `ferias`? It's not clear how the two tables relate to each other. I'm afraid it's also not clear what your expected results are, so could you show those too?

Answer (score 1):

Since both of your tables has a column named `idfunc`; just do a natural join which will match the table on common field or column; in this case `idfunc` like below

```
SELECT ferias.* FROM ferias NATURAL JOIN funcionarios
```

See more on mysql joins [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, what you need is just an inner join and order by

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ferias fer INNER JOIN funcionarios func ON func.idfunc = 
fer.idfunc ORDER BY idfunc DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want all rows in `ferias` that have an `idfunc` that is in `functionaris`. You can accomplish that with the following query:

```
SELECT ferias.idfunc FROM ferias JOIN functionarios ON ferias.idfunc = functionarios.idfunc
```

`a JOIN b` will only return rows that exist in both `a` and `b`. You can find the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).